# Python/PostgreSQL insert row having no effect

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using the pg8000 module to connect a python script to a postgreSQL database and I want to insert some new rows.  When I run the script I get no errors and it appears to run fine, but when I check the table afterwards, nothing was actually added to it.

What is confusing me is that if I print out the query statement I am executing with the pg8000 cursor object, and then just copy/paste and execute it in the pgadmin interface, it properly inserts a new row.

Another strange thing is that the table has an ID field which is based on a SERIAL, auto-updating itself every time a row is inserted.  This serial is updating when I run the script.  I can tell b/c the next ID to add, for example, is 6000.  If I run the script (which should add about 1000 rows but doesnt), then insert a row manually, the new row has an ID of 7000.

Here's the loop creating and executing the statements:

```
for row in new_signs:
    query = "INSERT INTO {0}_signs (source_link, destination_link, exit_number) VALUES ({1},{2},'{3}');".format(city,row[0],row[1],row[2])
    print query
    cursor.execute(query)
```

And some example output:

```
INSERT INTO osm_newyork_signs (source_link, destination_link, exit_number) VALUES (56423,1833854,'26');
INSERT INTO osm_newyork_signs (source_link, destination_link, exit_number) VALUES (353212,310961,'45');
INSERT INTO osm_newyork_signs (source_link, destination_link, exit_number)    VALUES (203823,1862344,'63N');
```

And the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.osm_newyork_signs
(
  source_link integer NOT NULL,
  destination_link integer NOT NULL,
  exit_number text,
  "Branch_RouteID" character varying(64),
  "Branch_RouteDir" character varying(6),
  "Sign_TextType" character varying(6),
  "Sign_Text" character varying(255),
  "Toward_RouteID" character varying(64),
  "Straight_On" character varying(255),
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('osm_newyork_signs_id_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT newyork_signs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT check_branch_toward CHECK ("Sign_TextType"::text = 'B'::text OR     "Sign_TextType"::text = 'T'::text OR "Sign_TextType" IS NULL)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: Do you by any chance use a session and forgot to commit the queries?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  I just create a connection using

    conn = pg.connect(user='', password='', host='', database='')  
    cursor = conn.cursor()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since autocommit is off by default unless you explicitly call `conn.commit()`, any actions done in the transaction will be undone. However, ID numbers are not rolled back and hence you are seeing that behavior.

You have two options:

1. explicitly commit after performing execute statements:

```
    conn.commit()
```

2. enable autocommit on your DB connection (before you create cursor):

```
    conn.autocommit = True
```

You can read more about this at http://pythonhosted.org/pg8000/quickstart.html#key-points

Comment: I was thinking the commit came from the cursor, so when I didn't see a cursor.commit method on the documentation I figured it was on by default.  Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why the serial ID would change without a commit?